# CSScript script giving error with Timer

Tags: c#, .net

I have a script that I want to use a Timer in but I'm getting an error "Additional information: {interactive}(11,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Timer' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

My host app is a console app but I've included the System.Windows.Forms dll in the references.

Here is the code. Why would I be getting this error?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Script : GameScript
{
public int Interval = 5000;
public bool StartOnLoad = true;

public event EventHandler OnTick;

Timer tmrTimer;
}
```

Comment: try adding `using System.Timers;`

Comment: Additional information: {interactive}(11,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Timer' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

{interactive}(37,49): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ElapsedEventArgs' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Are your sure you have included the System.Windows.Forms dll in the references?

Answer (score 0):

I came accross a similar problem using CSScript.
It appeared that adding a reference and including the using statements in the script are not enough.
If the application does not use any object from the referenced assembly, it seems that the assembly is ignored and not included in the compiled application and the script cannot see it.

Try creating a timer in your application hosting your script.